# Why Math.PI is flagged non-enumerable?

Tags: javascript, browser, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

I executed this small piece of code:

```
 Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Math, 'PI');
```

The output is
     {value: 3.141592653589793, writable: false, enumerable: false, configurable: false}

It makes sense that Math.PI has writable flag set to false because it is a constant and should'nt be changed. And to make even writable flag unchangable the configurable flag is also set to false. But Why is enumerable flag set to false? Why it should'nt be enumerated?

Comment: Well, the `enumerable` property has to have some value and I see no particular reason it would be enumerable or not be enumerable.  Basically, you generally don't enumerate the `Math` object at all so either the value is somewhat random (no reason one way or the other) or when there's no particular reason to make it enumerable, you make it non-enumerable.

Answer (score 0):

Actually all properties of `Math` are not enumerable. Thats probably because:

```
  for(const prop of Math) {
   console.log(prop);
  }
```

makes little sense.